# Overloading virtual << operator c++

Tags: c++11, operator-overloading, virtual

I have the following code in io.h:

```
  #include <iostream>
  #include "shape.h"

  class IODevice { // Interface for displaying CAD objects  
  public:
     virtual void operator << (const Circle&  c) = 0;
     virtual void operator << (const Line&  c) = 0;
  };

  class CmdIODevice : public IODevice {
      void operator << (const Circle&  c);
      void operator << (const Line& c);
  };
```

and shape.h :

```
#pragma once
#include "io.h"

class Shape {
public:
    virtual void display(IODevice& ioDevice) = 0;
};

class Circle : public Shape {
public:
    void display(IODevice& ioDevice);
};


class Line : public Shape {
public:
    void display(IODevice& ioDevice);
}
};
```

and get the following error when I declare the virtual operator in IODevice:
Error   C4430   missing type specifier - int assumed. Note: C++ does not support default-int

Apparently Circle is not seen by the compiler, I do not understand, please help.

Comment: Looks like the second file you pasted needs to #include io.h.

Comment: sorry, just a paste error, I modified it this is not the problem. Thanks.

Comment: What's in `shape.h`?

Comment: shape.h is the second code (I edited my post), I did not put the definition. It looks like the compiler cannot see Circle because both declarations require the other. I might need a preprocessor directive, thanks for helping